# is there a way to get clients IP addresses through this PHP form

Tags: php, ip-address

is there a way to get clients IP addresses through this PHP form or can someone help the right way to get the ip adress here.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','phone','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);
$validator->field('countryCode')->maxLength(20);
$validator->field('phone')->maxLength(20);


$pp->requireCaptcha();

 
$pp = getIPAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);  



$pp->sendEmailTo('someone@mail.com'); 

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

    function getRealIP(){

        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

        }elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        }elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];

        }elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        }elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"])){

            return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];

        }else{

            return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        }
    }       
?>
```

Comment: You might want to use a `switch` statement in this case, because it would make the code appear more organized, and it's usually considered good practice to use a `switch` instead of a long `if/else/else if`. Also, explaining the individual members of the `$_SERVER` array, or linking to the documentation, might help future users with a similar problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that the [Forwarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded) and [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) headers can contain a whole lot more information than just a single IP address.